# Trouble applying javaScript in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to apply the javascript below in an html file, this code is part of a plugin so I know that it works for sure, but I'm have trouble defining it with  tags, no matter what I try the script won't run.

Once the user scrolls past a div, that div becomes stuck to the top of the page:

```
$(function() {
   var a = function() {
   var b = $(window).scrollTop();
   var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset({scroll:false}).top;
   var c=$("#scroller");
   if (b>d) {
       c.css({position:"fixed",top:"0px"})
   } else if (b<=d) {
       c.css({position:"relative",top:""})
   }
 };
 $(window).scroll(a);a()
});​
```

I tried using the tag below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but that didn't work.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: The function stated is never executed. It should be `$(function() { ... })();`.

Comment: @arxanas its called on window scroll, the function is assigned to the variable a. There is no need for the "a()" after.

Comment: @arxanas: That's not right. OP is passing a function to the `$` function as a callback for `.ready()`. If you tried to run your example, it would give a *TypeError*.

Comment: Forgive me; I thought that $ would return a function which should then be executed.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zsJAr/

Comment: so, that fiddle looks like it works fine. What's failing?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need the type attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

You could then throw that source in if you'd like, just add that attribute on.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and that should be the proper way to include whatever is in that code into your page.

Comment: I've had problems with doing this and it still not working. Try putting your code within script tags into the actual page. If that works, then holler. We'll figure out how to reference it elsewhere.

Comment: Type attribute is not required in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

if you are manipulating the DOM, you will also need to wrap your code with DOMReady:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Code goes here

});
```

Comment: DOMReady makes the Jquery wait until the page is loaded, so that it wont try to manipulate elements that arent there.